# 2 arrays to map in Java. Values array may contain null elements

Tags: java, java-8

I have 2 arrays (same size) `String[]` and `Object[]`.
The question: is there a more elegant way to convert them to Map than this?

```
private Map<String, Object> arraysToMap(String[] keys, Object[] values) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    if (keys.length != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            map.put(keys[i], values[i]);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Java 8 style maybe?

Important notes:

- `values` may contain null value
- `keys` contains non-null unique elements

Comment: make sure that the sizes are equal, otherwise you might get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you can use the following code:

```
public class Test {
    static String[] keys = {"String1", "String2"};
    static Object[] values = {new Object(), new Object()};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> map = IntStream.range(0, keys.length)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> keys[i], i -> values[i]));
    }
}
```

As can you see first I have created a range from zero to `keys.length`, then we have replaced the primitive values of the stream with their corresponding object wrapper classes. At the end we used `Collectors.toMap` method to actually create the map. Also make sure that the sizes to be equal.

Comment: There is a problem.
That fails with NPE if one of values is null.

Comment: This was happening because the array were not initialized. It was an example but please see my updated answer.

Comment: nope
I checked with these 2 arrays:
[
  "externalOrderId",
  "isEadIncluded",
  "cookieToken"
]

[
  "C605607731",
  true,
  null
]

still NPE

Comment: If you have a value which is `null` inside an array, MPE will be thrown. You to need to filter for non-null values.

Comment: If array values contains null it fails at collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> keys[i], i -> values[i]))

Comment: but `Map` supports null values, that's why I don't want to for filter non-null values

Comment: Map itself supports null values but overridden merge() method from HashMap does not. 
`@Override
    public V merge(K key, V value,
                   BiFunction<? super V, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
        if (value == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();`

Comment: @AlexMamo you example can be extended with "dirty hack" :) Following code will work because Hashtable's merge() implementation accepts null values
   
        `Map<String, Object> map = IntStream.range(0, keys.length)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> keys[i], i -> values[i], (v1, v2) -> v1, Hashtable::new));
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>(map);`

Comment: Good try Nikolay, now there is no NPE anymore.
The bad news is there are no key-value pairs like this {"key", null}.
That works like a filter for non-null values.
Looks like only the old good "for loop" style works (see in the question).

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko why do that instead of simply proving the merge function yourself? If the merge function is hit in the first place, it means for the same key there are at least two possible values (of which one is null), you probably want to keep the one that is non-null; or both - but in this case the definition needs to change to  `Map<String, List<Object>>`

Comment: @Lenar of course not. define the `merge` function to `Collectors.toMap` as you please (which btw you have not specified in your question or your code). so what exactly should happen when there are two values for one key and one of them is potentially null? always keep the non-null one? what if they are both not null? unless you tell us those details, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: you're right I had to describe that case.
`keys` contains non-null unique elements. 

updated the question description

Comment: @Eugene you can provide custom `mergeFunction` to `Collectors.toMap()` but you can't provide custom method `merge()` implementation to `HashMap` class. That is crucial difference :)

Comment: OK, since this is flagged as a duplicate I cannot add my own answer as an answer. So I leave that as a comment. Hopefully that will be useful for someone else in community.   
  
    `public Map<String, Object> arraysToMap(String[] keys, Object[] values) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        IntStream.range(0, keys.length).boxed().forEach(i -> map.put(keys[i], values[i]));
        return map;
    }`

Comment: @azurefrog you might want to unflag it?

Comment: @Lenar its not about keys, its about values and how u want to merge them. Have u read my previous comment?

Comment: @Eugene I see what you mean. I don't wanna merge them because I don't expect to have different values with same key. All keys are unique. That's what I have in my real project.

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko right, I should have made myself more clear. what I meant is that you can build a custom collector and provide the merge function as you want (if one is needed)

Comment: @Lenar got it. then it could be done like this: `Map<String, String> r = IntStream.range(0, keys.length)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collector.of(
                        HashMap::new,
                        (map, x) -> {
                            map.put(keys[x], values[x]);

                        },
                        (left, right) -> {
                            left.putAll(right);
                            return left;
                        }));`

Comment: it's complaining about `values[x]`. Expected `java.lang.String`.
Anyway thank you @Eugene

Comment: @Lenar I like how u throw code at us, without posting it in the question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162176/discussion-between-lenar-and-eugene).